# after opening terminal process quits and cannot access terminal again

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm on a mac OS X

I wanted to install an extension to the zsh shell --> Oh-my-zsh:

I ran the following commands using the Iterminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
sudo sh -c "echo '/usr/local/bin/zsh' >> /etc/shells"
```

After the above command the process chocked and I could not change the current shell to the zsh shell

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

After this I closed the iTerminal, restarted it but it would not really load. Clicking on the application opened the iTerminal window for a second and then closes again.

The same does also happen to the regular terminal window. I click on the application the terminal opens but get the following message:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/zsh: No such file or directory
```

It seems as the previous command crocked the load direction for the terminal to load the correct shell is screwed up.

Does any one know how I can reset this to the previous shell without having access to the terminal window.

Answer (score 38):

After trying I solved this problem. To permanently change your default Terminal shell:

1. Choose Preferences from the Terminal menu.
2. Select the option "Execute this command (specify complete path):"
3. Change the selected text entry from /bin/tcsh to reflect a different Terminal shell, such as:

   ```
    /bin/bash 
    /bin/csh 
    /bin/zsh 
    /bin/zsh-4.0.4 (Mac OS X 10.2.8 or earlier) 
    /bin/zsh-4.1.1 (Mac OS X 10.3 or later) 
    /bin/ksh (Mac OS X 10.4 or later)
   ```
4. Close the Terminal Preferences window.
5. Quit and open Terminal again. The first and subsequent new Terminal windows open with the shell that you designated in Preferences.

Answer (score 29):

On MAC:

1. Go to "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups"
2. Click the "Lock" icon and authenticate
3. Right-click the your user icon and select "Advanced Options"
4. Change the value for "Login shell" to /bin/bash

Comment: this is the only option i had on iTerm2. it disabled the Preferences when zsh (my default shell) failed.

Answer (score 7):

just choose preferences from the terminal menu and select the option shells open with "command (complete path)" and type this path:

/bin/bash

Answer (score -1):

maybe need install zsh first;

```
brew install zsh
```